# How to test if button text has been changed in Espresso Android?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to test a login page using Espresso in Android.So far I have identified the test cases that my code should perform. These are the test cases

> - Enter User Name
> - Enter Password
> - Press Submit
> - Check Button text changed to "Verifying..."

This is my test case

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LoginTest {
private String userName;
private String userPass;

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity>(LoginActivity.class);

  @Before
  public void assignCredentials (){
    userName = "ABC";
    userPass = "ABC";
  }

  @Test
  public void buttonTextChanged(){
    onView(withId(R.id.edittext_user))
            .perform(typeText(userName));
    onView(withId(R.id.edittext_pass))
            .perform(typeText(userPass));
    onView(withId(R.id.submit_login))
            .perform(click())
            .check(matches(withText("Verifying...")));
  }
}
```

To add, Login button text is actually changing the text to ***Verifying...*** when the system is checking the credentials with server and once done, the text changes to ***LOGIN*** again. Every time I run, the test fails and showing the actual text is ***LOGIN*** . I am assuming, this is happening because of the delay and espresso could not catch the delay. As I am new in testing, I would be grateful if you could explain how this problem can be resolved or what is the approach that I should take for this kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

There are few things I would try in your case:

### Api Call

Generally speaking you should avoid "contacting" the real server when performing the test. You need to isolate the thing you're really testing so you cannot hope that the api call succeeds.
You need to be sure what comes back from your backend.

There are two ways people usually fix this:

1. Mock the api call to return proper thing without even touching the network stack
2. Mock the Http server

The exact implementation of any of the above depends on how your app is designed.

### Time-related stuff

Although Espresso should manage any events that it should wait for, sometimes there's a need to tell it to delay some executions manually.

For that purpose you should use [`IdlingResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.html). A nice, simple explanation on that subject can be found [here](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/espresso-custom-idling-resource.html).

Additionally if you use any `Animations` in the thing you're testing, you should disable them for the time of your tests. There are multiple ways of doing so, a simple google search will give you tons of questions here on StackOverflow.

### Espresso calls

I'm not sure if that makes any difference (would have to look deeper into Espresso code), but the last thing I would do is to separate two Espresso calls you're performing. To be sure that Espresso executes the `click()` first, and then checks `matches` and not both of them at the same time.

```
@Test
public void buttonTextChanged(){
  onView(withId(R.id.edittext_user))
          .perform(typeText(userName));
  onView(withId(R.id.edittext_pass))
          .perform(typeText(userPass));
  onView(withId(R.id.submit_login))
          .perform(click());
  onView(withId(R.id.submit_login))
          .check(matches(withText("Verifying...")));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I appreciate your effort for giving me a detailed instruction, I will surely look at it and come back.I have already disabled Animation in emulator before starting the test.The last but not the least, the segment "Espresso calls" , I have tried the approach before but it did not work as well.

Comment: bro, I have followed your guideline though I did not mock the web server. After implementing the IdlingResources as it is time related stuff, I am getting some exception and still the problem resides that I can not track the changed button text . You can have a look at this post 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934310/testing-login-with-espresso-is-throwing-exception