# Espresso throw " Error performing 'single click' on view” when it run on device in the cloud, but same test successfully run locally

Tags: firebase, android-espresso

I fill up user name and password and press a button that sends the information over the network (Espresso Idling resource is implemented), in the application the next screen appears and I can see in logs that the information has being sent.
But the test fails with error that it was not able to press the button:
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'with id:

Log:

> 10-03 07:36:30.308: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0
>   10-03 07:36:30.308: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0
>   10-03 07:36:30.318: I/ViewInteraction(27742): Performing 'replace
>   text' action on view with id: com._:id/user_name 10-03 07:36:30.358:
>   D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03 07:36:30.358:
>   D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03 07:36:30.358:
>   I/ViewInteraction(27742): Performing 'replace text' action on view
>   with id: com._:id/password 10-03 07:36:30.388:
>   D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03 07:36:30.388:
>   D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0
>   **10-03 07:36:30.388: I/ViewInteraction(27742): Performing 'single click' action on view with id: com._:id/Button** 10-03 07:36:30.398:
>   I/InputDispatcher(3416): Delivering touch to (3959): action: 0x4,
>   toolType: 0 10-03 07:36:30.398: I/InputDispatcher(3416): Delivering
>   touch to (27742): action: 0x0, toolType: 0 10-03 07:36:30.398:
>   D/ViewRootImpl(27742): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN 10-03
>   07:36:30.408: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.408: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.428: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.428: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.438: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.438: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.448: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.448: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.458: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.458: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.458: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.458: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.478: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.478: D/_IdlingResource(27742): _ is idle now! with: 0 10-03
>   07:36:30.488: I/InputDispatcher(3416): Delivering touch to (27742):
>   action: 0x1, toolType: 0 10-03 07:36:30.498: D/Request(27742): method:
>   1 url: https://.

******  I removed Network calls     **********

> 10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):
>   android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing
>   'single click - At Coordinates: 719, 1367 and precision: 16, 16' on
>   view 'with id: com.*:id/Button'. 10-03 07:37:30.538:
>   I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   Pages*._LinkAccountPage.clickOnLinkAccountButton(*LinkAccountPage.java:62)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   Pages*._LinkAccountPage.linkAccount(*LinkAccountPage.java:40) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   JunitTest*.Test_BaseEspresso.searchAndLinkBill(Test_BaseEspresso.java:138)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   JunitTest_.Test_LinkFiCreditKycPayCurrentBalanceNewAchReceiptCancel.Test_LinkFiCreditKycPayCurrentBalanceNewAchReceiptCancel(Test_LinkFiCreditKycPayCurrentBalanceNewAchReceiptCancel.java:41)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 10-03 07:37:30.538:
>   I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 10-03 07:37:30.538:
>   I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) 10-03 07:37:30.538:
>   I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) 10-03 07:37:30.538:
>   I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):    at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) 10-03 07:37:30.538:
>   I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) 10-03 07:37:30.538:
>   I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1889)
>              ************** note error below** 10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742): Caused by:
>   **android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 3585 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .**
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.IdlingPolicy.handleTimeout(IdlingPolicy.java:61)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:480)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:411)
>   10-03 07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742):  at
>   android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMo 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742): ----- end exception ----- 10-03
>   07:37:30.538: I/TestRunner(27742): finished:
>   Test_LinkFiCreditKycPayCurrentBalanceNewAchReceiptCancel(JunitTest_.Test_LinkFiCreditKycPayCurrentBalanceNewAchReceiptCancel)
>   10-03 07:37:30.578: I/MonitoringInstrumentation(27742): Activities
>   that are still in CREATED to STOPPED: 3 10-03 07:37:30.578:
>   I/MonitoringInstrumentation(27742): Finishing activity:
>   com.*.core.provider.AddProviderActivity@3f31fd61 10-03 07:37:30.578:
>   V/ApplicationPolicy(3416): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname
>   com.* 10-03 07:37:30.578: V/ApplicationPolicy(3416):
>   isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com._ 10-03 07:37:30.578:
>   D/InputDispatcher(3416): Focused application set to: xxxx 10-03
>   07:37:30.588: I/ActivityManager(3416): Skip updateThumbnail for
>   r=ActivityRecord{23d1bfe2 u0 com.*/.core.provider.AddProviderActivity
>   t5 f} 10-03 07:37:30.588: I/MonitoringInstrumentation(27742):
>   Finishing activity:
>   com.*.core.overview.NewUserSignUpIntroScreen@18c65aea 10-03
>   07:37:30.598: I/MonitoringInstrumentation(27742): Finishing activity:
>   com.*.core.provider.SearchProviderActivity@33d373f6 10-03
>   07:37:30.598: V/ApplicationPolicy(3416): isApplicationStateBlocked
>   userId 0 pkgname com.* 10-03 07:37:30.598: V/ApplicationPolicy(3416):
>   isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname
>   com.google.android.apps.mtaas.backdrop 10-03 07:37:30.598:
>   D/InputDispatcher(3416): Focused application set to: xxxx 10-03
>   07:37:30.598: D/MultiWindowConverter(3416): dismissGuide() : Before
>   attaching the guide view, mForceDismissGuide : false 10-03
>   07:37:30.598: D/InputDispatcher(3416): Focus left window: 27742 10-03
>   07:37:30.598: I/TestRunner(27742): run finished: 1 tests, 1 failed, 0
>   ignored 10-03 07:37:30.608: I/System.out(27742): (HTTPLog)-Static:
>   isSBSettingEnabled false 10-03 07:37:30.608: D/PointerIcon(3416):
>   setMouseIconStyle1 pointerType: 1001 iconType:101 flag:0 pid:3416
>   uid:1000 10-03 07:37:30.608: D/PointerIcon(3416): setMouseCustomIcon
>   IconType is same.101 10-03 07:37:30.608: D/EnterpriseController(2962):
>   mIsMarkChainAdded is 0 mIsBlockChainAdded is 0 netId is 0 10-03
>   07:37:30.608: D/Netd(2962): getNetworkForDns: using netid 502 for uid
>   10207 10-03 07:37:30.608: D/Lifecycle(27742): onActivityPaused:
>   core.provider.AddProviderActivity

Comment: Did you ever find what was causing this?

Comment: I have the same issue, test is failing after the view already been clicked and the application went to the next screen.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of error appears when you are working on a screen whose fields are hidden behind the soft keyboard. Thus, you should do a couple of things:

1. Make the layout scrollable and using *ViewActions.scrollTo* perform the scroll to that field.
2. Close que soft keyboard using *ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard*

An example:

```
String OLD_PWD_INPUT = "Asdf1234;";
onView(withId(R.id.old_password)).perform(typeText(OLD_PWD_INPUT));
onView(withId(R.id.verify_new_password)).perform(closeSoftKeyboard());
onView(withId(R.id.change_password_button)).check(matches(not(isEnabled())));

String NEW_PWD_INPUT = "Asdf1235;";
onView(withId(R.id.new_password)).perform(scrollTo());
onView(withId(R.id.new_password)).perform(typeText(NEW_PWD_INPUT));
onView(withId(R.id.verify_new_password)).perform(closeSoftKeyboard());
onView(withId(R.id.change_password_button)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
```